# How do I get navigation bar titles to wrap on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

With a button in each corner, most of the titles in my navigation bar end up being truncated with "...".

Is there any way to make the title wrap?

I know changing the height is tricky, but if I set the prompt to an empty string "" then it seems to increase the height, so I'm hoping I can get the title to wrap into that space.